# Suppress confirmation prompts in IOS when copying files

Tags: cisco, cisco-ios

I am about to upgrade the IOS on several hundred Cisco VG224's in preparation for a CUCM upgrade.

I am attempting to streamline/automate this process as much as possible, and currently my main problem is the "confirmation" prompts that IOS gives back for the `copy` command.  For example:

```
GW-TEST#copy scp://USER:PASSWORD@SERVER//path/path/vg224-i6k9s-mz.151-4.M7.bin slot0:vg224-i6k9s-mz.151-4.M7.bin
Destination filename [vg224-i6k9s-mz.151-4.M7.bin]? 
Translating "SERVER"...domain server (192.168.101.2) [OK] 
 Sending file modes: C0644 28935060 vg224-i6k9s-mz.151-4.M7.bin
!!! ::SNIP:: !!!!
28935060 bytes copied in 501.532 secs (57693 bytes/sec)

GW-TEST#
```

I have found the appropriate syntax to have the device not prompt me for the username or password every time.

But now, no matter what I do, it still prompts me to confirm the `Destination filename [vg224-i6k9s-mz.151-4.M7.bin]`.

Is there a way to stop this behavior?

Comment: Have you thought about using SNMP to do the copy's?

Comment: I have.  I'm familiar with the [CISCO-FLASH-MIB](http://tools.cisco.com/Support/SNMP/do/BrowseMIB.do?local=en&step=2&mibName=CISCO-FLASH-MIB) if that's what you're referring to.   This particular install has no SNMP write access unfortunately.  Changing the SNMP policies in the timeline I was working with wasn't reasonable.

Comment: ok, fallback: do they have `ip scp server enable`?  at any rate, it looks like some configuration change (even if temp) will be required.

Comment: They don't have it enabled, but that is a really good idea.  Push it to the devices via SCP instead of pulling it down from the device via SCP.  I've already completed this project, but I'll keep that in mind for next time.  Thanks @RickyBeam!

Comment: what is to suppress confirmation prompts?

Comment: @Brian I was attempting to prevent IOS from asking for confirmation of all the settings during a file copy.  That way, it could be easily setup for an unattended script.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The command you're looking for is `file prompt quiet`.

If you change this setting in Global Configuration mode, it will suppress the confirmation alerts you're seeing and allow one line, automated file operations.

However, it is worth noting that for the most part, the confirmation prompts are there to protect your system and "CYA"...  If you feed the wrong information into your file operations, you could potentially interrupt service on this device.

If you do disable the file prompts, I would make sure that one of the last steps in your script is to reset it to the default of `file prompt alert`.

See [this Cisco PDF](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/ios/fundamentals/command/reference/cf_f1.pdf) for more information.